# Ajax call spring controller always fail

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call to a spring controller, then write the returned data to DOM. 
Direct access controller in browser works fine and displays a string.
Run the ajax in debugger showing that ajax call fired and controller got called, then ajax call always failed. Any suggestion? Here's my code.

servlet-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.controller" />
```

controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myAjaxHandler")
public void myAjaxHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.getWriter().println("Hello");
}
```

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/dispatcher/myAjaxHandler',
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `myAjaxCall()` insted of `var myAjaxCall = function() = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `myAjaxCall`? You just define this function.

Comment: I have this in my javascript, but it only print out the whole function text, didn't fire.

if (myAjaxCall != "false")
 alert(myAjaxCall);

Comment: `alert(myAjaxCall)` just shows the function's definition. You need call via `myAjaxCall()`(note the parenthese).

Comment: Thanks, now it fires the call :)

Comment: you may check if there is any exception, or add `complete` callback and see if it's called. BTW, `success`, `error`, `complete` are deprecated, you'd better replace them by `done`, `fail` and `always`.

Comment: I saw the code running into method myAjaxHandler and returned, why do I get "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" for "../dispatcher/myAjaxHandler" in XHR?

Comment: "404 not found" means the url you specify doesn't exist in the server. Check the url and server side code.

Comment: well, that is my spring controller path, ajax called it and job is done. I guess it could not be treated as a url, right?

Comment: So that's not your ajax's fault. Fix it first.